# Can't create file while the application running

Tags: java, playframework

I'm having a weird issue.

I have this path I want to use for my application:

```
private final String PNG_PATH = "cache/plugins/sonarrtv/images/";
```

If the folder doesn't exist, i'll create it. This works without problem but once I want to create files into this folder it fails but only when I run on a deployed application using the 'stage' command. If I run it ./activator run then it works

```
[info] - application - FULL_PNG Path: /Users/gz/Cloud/Dev/Java/HomeDash/target/universal/stage/cache/plugins/sonarrtv/images Writable ? false
[info] - application - f Path: /Users/gz/Cloud/Dev/Java/HomeDash/target/universal/stage/cache/plugins/sonarrtv/images/247808-fanart.jpg
```

It says that the folder isn't writable. I tried to set it as writable programmatically, but no difference. I checked and I am the owner of the new folder created so it shouldn't be an issue.

Here's the code I use to create the folder:

```
File f = new File(PNG_PATH);
if (!f.exists()) {
    f.mkdirs();
}
f.setWritable(true);
f.deleteOnExit();
```

and here how I create the file:

```
File f = new File(PNG_PATH + series.getSeriesId() + "-fanart.jpg");
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new java.net.URL(poster), f);
```

Comment: Can you please update the code you are using for creating the folder/changing the permissions/creating the file?

Comment: I notice you do not use a full path but a relative path. Are you sure you have write permission to the location when you run with 'stage'. You could try specifying a full path (starting at root).

Comment: @Kris yeah, the weird part is that i can create the folder, but i can't write create file into it. I checked, the file are exactly where they should be, in the stage folder. Before Play 2.4.0 i could set the full path with Play.application().getPath() or something like this, but since 2.4.0 it throws errors that Play hasn't started and someone recommended me not to use this anymore, so I'm trying to find an alternative to full path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find a better way. I'm actually loading the user.dir from the config using the following:

```
ConfigFactory.load().getString("user.dir")+"/cache/";
```

This works in every stage of the application life cycle. Play.application().getPath() would throw errors if called on an eager bound singleton saying that the application is not started.